# How can I maximize the width of an element between fixed-width elements?

Tags: html, css

[image: :(]

My work seems like above. The width of left one (img) and right one (button) is fixed, and that of middle one (textarea) should be flexible.

It has to work like max-width property is given to it.

When the size of the window shrinks, the size of the textarea should also be shrunk.

But max-width property doesn't work well in this case.

When the size of the window reaches the length of A, width of the textarea should be start shrinking, but it doesn't.

Instead, it starts shrinking when the width of the window reaches the length of B.

Below shows what happens when the window shrinks.

[image]

What should I do for this problem with css? Or do I need to use javascript?

html

```
<div id="div_target">
    <p>
        <img src="~~~"/>
    </p>
    <p> 
        <textarea id="target" cols="40"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="등록"/>
    </p>
</div>
```

css

```
#div_target{
    width:60%;
}
#target{
    max-width:60%;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one method using CSS flexbox:

```css
#div_target{
    display: flex;
    width: 60%;
}
#div_target > * {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="div_target">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/50/50">
  <textarea id="target" cols="40"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="등록" />
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8rkjmevp/)

Comment: Thanks! 'flexbox' can be well applied for my code with little modification.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly your problem is shrinking the width of textarea in the small size devices.
Try below structure:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 target">
    <div >
      <img src="~~~"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="등록"/>
    </div>   
  </div>

.target{
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 textarea{
   width: 60%;
 }
```

I believe you want to have the element inline in the "md" and "lg" so you can define: 
display: inline-block;
for the elements in the large devices.

Comment: Ah.. no, That's not the point. The problem is "it doesn't start shrinking in proper moment", not "it shrinks in the small device".

Comment: You must change the width of the textarea in the media query you aim to change the size.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.target{
      text-align: center;
      display:block;
    }
    textarea{
      width: 60%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 target">
    <div >
      <img src="http://orig05.deviantart.net/8ac4/f/2011/297/5/6/hammer_bro__by_yoshigo99-d4duynn.png"style="width:50px;height:50px;"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="등록"/>
    </div>   
  </div>
```